# asp:chart, charttype='column' with legend visible

Tags: asp.net, mschart

I am a bit confused with Asp:Chart, I have a table that returns one row

[image]

now I want it to be displayed in Asp:chart with ChartType="Column".

1. I converted the above table into the format

   [image]

   I used one series

   ```
   <asp:Chart ID="charttest" runat="server" Width="950px" Height="250px">
               <Series>
                   <asp:Series Name="Categories" IsValueShownAsLabel="true"        
          ChartArea="MainChartArea"
                       ChartType="Column" Legend="legend1"  >
                   </asp:Series>
                 </Series>
               <ChartAreas>
                   <asp:ChartArea Name="MainChartArea" Area3DStyle-Enable3D="true" 
                            Area3DStyle-IsClustered="true" BorderWidth="1" 
                          Area3DStyle-WallWidth="1" Area3DStyle-
                        PointGapDepth="50" Area3DStyle-PointDepth="100" Area3DStyle-                    
                          Rotation="10">

                   </asp:ChartArea>
               </ChartAreas>
              <Legends>
            <asp:Legend Name="legend1" BorderColor="Blue" ></asp:Legend>
              </Legends>
           </asp:Chart>
   ```

   Problem:

   a. The graph was showing properly but there was only one legend, couldn't change the label into percentage from code behind.
2. Then, I used multiple series but

   ```
      <asp:Chart ID="charttest" runat="server" Width="950px" 
                Height="250px">
               <Series>
                   <asp:Series Name="Categories" IsValueShownAsLabel="true"   
                    ChartArea="MainChartArea"
                       ChartType="Column" Legend="legend1"  >
                   </asp:Series>
                   <asp:Series Name="Categories2" IsValueShownAsLabel="true" 
                      ChartArea="MainChartArea"
                       ChartType="Column" Legend="legend1" >
                   </asp:Series>
                   <asp:Series Name="Categories3" IsValueShownAsLabel="true" 
                  ChartArea="MainChartArea"
                       ChartType="Column" Legend="legend1" >
                   </asp:Series>
                   <asp:Series Name="Categories4" IsValueShownAsLabel="true" 
                     ChartArea="MainChartArea"
                       ChartType="Column" Legend="legend1" >
                  </asp:Series>
                      </Series>
                  <ChartAreas>
                   <asp:ChartArea Name="MainChartArea" Area3DStyle-Enable3D="true"  
                       Area3DStyle-IsClustered="true" BorderWidth="1" Area3DStyle- 
                       WallWidth="1" Area3DStyle-PointGapDepth="50" Area3DStyle-
                        PointDepth="100" Area3DStyle-Rotation="10">

                   </asp:ChartArea>
               </ChartAreas>
              <Legends>
            <asp:Legend Name="legend1" BorderColor="Blue" ></asp:Legend>
              </Legends>
           </asp:Chart>
   ```

   Problem:

   a. The legend was showing properly and I was able to show label in percentage but the axis value weren't getting displayed, It must be displaying those bars with space between them.

[image]

Can you tell me how should I solve this problem.

1. Use single or multiple series to solve this problem. I did lots of research but couldn't find a perfect solution.
2. A column name must be displayed just below each block.

Answer (score 2):

For your second question, "A column name must be displayed just below each block." you would want to add an AxisLabel to each of your DataPoints under your series.

```
<asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Celtics" YValues="17" />
```

Here is a [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203246/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072209-1.aspx) I found that shows an example.